# MongoDB - import csv

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport, csv-import

I am importing a csv from command prompt using mongoimport statement.

Some of the description fields in my csv contains blank lines in their value, which is breaking when I am importing the csv into mongoDB. (Please note - When I am viewing the same csv in excel, it is coming out to be perfect)

There is a message on command prompt when I run mongoimport command, as follows:

"CSV file ends while inside quoted field".

It did not solve my problem either.

Here is an example that defines my CSV

*Input CSV format*

**Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4**

*Values:*
**Val1,Val2,Val3**

**Val1,"abcdsc \n \n \n some text",Val3**

Please advise how can I proceed further

Comment: What version of mongoimport are you using (`mongoimport --version`), and what O/S?

Comment: Version  : version 2.6.3
and 
I am using it with .net MVC on Windows 7

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: Here it is :

`mongoimport --db dbName --collection CollectionName-20140903211347 --type csv --headerline --file filePath.csv`

Comment: this issue could appear when you have `null` fields in your collection. Check your csv file and fix it manually, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

try [mongoimport manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoimport/)

```
--ignoreBlanks
```

> ```
> In csv and tsv exports, ignore empty fields. If not specified, mongoimport creates fields without values in imported documents.
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, the trick is not working in my case.

The result is still the same, I just noticed that there is a message on command prompt when I run this command.

"CSV file ends while inside quoted field".

Please advise how can i proceed further

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817654/mongoimport-csv-file-ends-while-inside-quoted-field-error